# Can one Tensorflow session connect to two targets at the same time?

Tags: python, session, tensorflow, server

In Tensorflow, we could create a server using `server=tf.train.Server()`, and define a Tensorflow session to connect that server by `sess=tf.Session(server.target)`. Now if we create two (or more than two) servers, can a Tensorflow session connect to both of them at the same time?

For example, we define two servers:

- Local Server: `local_server = tf.train.Server(...).create_local_server()`
- Worker Server: `worker_server = tf.train.Server(cluster_spec)` with `cluster_spec = tf.train.ClusterSpec(
  {"ps": ["localhost:2222"],"worker": ["localhost:1111", "localhost:1112"]})`

In the above case, is it possible to define a single Tensorflow session `tf.Session()` that connects to both "Local" and "Worker" servers in a single process? The goal is to make part of graph tensors compute on 1 server, and all the other part run on the other server.

Comment: how is it different from standard distributed tensorflow (different tensors can run on different workers)?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov The difference is not all tensor computations run on "worker" - Some may run on local with in-process execution engine, and others run on "worker".

Comment: The benefit is there's no communication cost for computations running on "local".

Comment: Where is the "worker" located? If "worker" is in the same process as your client there shouldn't be communication cost -- the commits in this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6256) mostly addressed this case to be as fast as tf.Session("local")

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov hmm... why there's no communication cost? My "worker" and "client" are in the same process, but isn't it true that "worker" is still the server, and client communicates internally with worker via grpc? I actually did profiling on my code, and I saw the cost there.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Also want to share that I compared running `tf.Session().run()` with `tf.Session(worker.target).run()` using the same feed_dict data, and the later one got ~25% more time to run, and I think the only possible reason is from the communication part.

Comment: There's a special fast path for this case of distributed tensorflow which avoids data copy, see the commits in the issue I linked. The 25% more time to run sounds like a snag, if you submit an issue with detailed benchmark it'll probably be addressed